# Adding a new column with count in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset that looks at reports to a manager and would like to create a new column that shows those counts.

What I have:

```
 ID    ManagerID 
 101      105
 102      103
 103      105
 104      103 
 105      110
```

Output I want:

```
ID      ManagerID      Count 
101       105             0
102       103             0
103       105             2
104       103             0
105       110             2
```

I have tried by doing:`df['count'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['ManagerID'].transform('nunique')` this gives me numbers that don't actually equal any of the value
s.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Running your code gives me all `1` in Count, as expected.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get your count values in expected output? Is the definition of `Count` = the number of reports for the ID in that row? Then since ID 4 didn't have any reports, the value should be 0?

Comment: Can you please provide, what you're trying to count exactly? because it's not very clear.

Comment: Why is the Count 2 for ManagerID = 10 ? If you count direct reports it should be 1. no?

Comment: @TYZ I made it a little easier to read but pretty much all IDs are in the ID column and only those who are Manager are in the Manager column and I want to see from the ID list how many of them Report to a manager in the manager list if that makes sense.

Comment: @LaassairiAbdellah I am trying to count the amount of times an 'ID' reports to a 'ManagerID' I edited the post to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @mozway Yeah I have a different code that works but I can't seem to get it to work when trying to make it a column and not a list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you might want:

```
df['count'] = df['ID'].map(df['ManagerID'].value_counts()).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Output:

```
   ID  ManagerID  count
0   1          5      0
1   2          3      0
2   3          5      2
3   4          3      0
4   5         10      2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count the number if reports for `ID`, then the following will work but yielding different result from your expected output as ID 4 doesn't have any reports:

```
pd.merge(df,
         df.ManagerID.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "ID", "ManagerID": "Count"}),
         on="ID",
         how="left",
         suffixes=("", "_y")).fillna(0)

   ID  ManagerID  Count
0   1          5    0.0
1   2          3    0.0
2   3          5    2.0
3   4          3    0.0
4   5         10    2.0
```